# Building from source Cmake for Scientific Linux 7.8

Tags: installation, cmake, centos, package, centos7

I installed cmake 3.12 (required packages for CERN ROOT); however, after typing "cmake --version" my terminal shows 2.8* as the current version.

After "tar" the file which i wget, I did the following:

```
cd cmake-3.12.3

./bootstrap --prefix=$HOME/opt/cmake3.12.3

make

make install
```

Why  is this happening?
what does ./bootstrap command mean or do here?

It is worth to mention I'm working on a server via ssh and I don't have any root privileges (and won't get them), so decided to build things from source.

I found few similar/related questions about my issues, but I'm a Linux novice and I didn't get too much from those answers.

Comment: Using `--prefix=$HOME/opt/cmake3.12.3` means that CMake will be installed under given directory. This directory normally is **not searched** for executables, so your installation isn't taken into account when you type `cmake`. You need to adjust `PATH` variable accordingly. (If you are novice in Linux and don't know what `PATH` variable means, I would suggest to learn that in the first place.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the comment! i have been reading about PATH and i better understand what's going on. I checked $HOME and i don't have any /opt directory. i would like to start again from scratch... now I'm told to use another path, which is /emph/app/ydeniz, to install all my programs. ydeniz is a new empty directory where i should set up everything i need... what would be an example for a good path for   --prefix= now?

Comment: You may choose any prefix. If the directory doesn't exist, it will be created automatically. After installation you need to adjust `PATH` variable correspondigly.

Comment: Oh! i got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the solution was the following:

1. choose a path to download the tar cmake* file and then untar
2. i create an additional directory called "local" somewhere else, make sure to know the path to this directory by using pwd (results should be of something like  /xxx/xxx/local)
3. enter the new cmake* directory (create when untar)

then

```
 cd cmake*
    ./bootstrap
    ./configure --prefix=/xxx/xxx/local #indicates the path for the installation
     make
     make install
```

On a new terminal, modify your .bashrc and .bash_profile by using any editor (i used nano) and add the following line to the file:

```
export PATH=/xxx/xxx/local/bin:${PATH} #indicates where to look when using cmake command.
```

save and quit

finally

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

now `cmake --version` should return your desire version